# R ggplot: Error bars on geom_bar with three responses

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

This is my code:

```
ggplot(data=simple, aes(x=as.factor(nOnset.fin), 
    fill=simple$stress <- factor(simple$stress, levels=ordered(c('1', '2', '3'))))) +
    geom_bar(position = 'fill') + 
    scale_fill_manual(aes(Stress), values=colours.fin, 
                      breaks = levels(simple$stress <- factor(simple$stress, levels=ordered(c('1', '2', '3'))))) + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format()) + theme_bw() + xlab('Size') + ylab(NULL) + 
    theme(text=element_text(size=35, family="CMU Sans Serif"), legend.position = 'none')
```

And this is the plot is generates:

https://copy.com/ghLt3z0iORicZtup

[image: plot]

My question is simple: **how do I add error bars to the darker blue bars** (the lighter two bars don't matter here). I've been trying this:

```
+ geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper, x=as.factor(nOnset.fin)))
```

And this is the error I've been getting:

> Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the
>   dataProblems:lower, upper

`lower` and `upper` in the code above are defined as:

```
se0 <- 1.96 * sd(simple$int.0) / sqrt(length(simple$int.0))

lower <- mean(simple$int.0) - se0
upper <- mean(simple$int.0) + se0
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: A `dput()` of the variables would help reproduce your current result.

Comment: Mapped aesthetics (those inside of `aes` need to be column in your data frame, or simple transformations of them). _Set_ aesthetics (those _outside_ of `aes()`) need to be a single value. Perhaps you meant to convert `stress` to a factor _first_, and then map fill to stress? The use of `<-` inside the `ggplot` call is very strange indeed.

Answer (score 0):

```
simple$nOnset.fin <- factor(simple$nOnset.fin)
simple$stress <- factor(simple$stress, levels=ordered(c('1', '2', '3')))
simple$se <- 1.96 * sd(simple$int.0) / sqrt(length(simple$int.0))
simple$lower <- mean(simple$int.0) - se0
simple$upper <- mean(simple$int.0) + se0

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(
  data = simple, 
  aes(x = nOnset.fin, fill = stress)
) +
  geom_bar(position = 'fill') + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=colours.fin) + 
  scale_y_continuous("", labels = percent) + 
  xlab('Size') + 
  theme_bw() +  
  theme(
    text = element_text(size=35, family="CMU Sans Serif"), 
    legend.position = 'none'
  )




library(fortunes)
fortune("tested solution")

Tested solutions offered when reproducible examples are provided.
   -- David Winsemius (suggesting a potential solution to a vague problem description)
      R-help (April 2011)
```